# How to remove every second column in Vim?

Tags: filetype

I have a CSV file where I want to remove every second column. Each column value are separated by quotes and the column values can contain field separators: this means that convenient solutions such as this AWK script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354082/print-every-nth-column-of-a-file) won't work out of the box because of extra delimiters that do not mean delimination of columns inside quotes. Please, try to find some native Vim solution for this.

### **How can I remove every second column in Vim?**

---

*Example data as asked in a comment*

```
"TakeMe","NotMe","TakeMe3","NotMe,4","Take,Me,5"
"1","2","3","4","5,"
"11","22","3,3","44","55"
```

and intended output

```
"TakeMe","TakeMe3","Take,Me,5"
"1","3","5,"
"11","3,3","55"
```

**Alternative approaches**

1. `:%!awk -F',' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }'`, then `%s@$@,@g` (separate column values), then `ggVGJ` (to join all values together with ^M as separators) and then `%s@\n@\n@` (to remove ^M in bad formated files to separate rows).
2. [Extract value between double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148285/extract-value-between-double-quotes) in Unix.SE
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804673/escaping-separator-within-double-quotes-in-awk
4. `%!cut -d '"' -f2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,...`

Comment: You can use the csv.vim plugin.

Comment: @Christian Brabandt can you show how? Or how would you do it with the plug-in? I use the plugin but haven't found a convenient way for this with it.

Comment: I suppose you also opened the corresponding issue at the plugin? I posted an [answer there](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim/issues/113#issuecomment-316852568).

Comment: You've stated that the column values can contain *commas* and included examples of this, but can they also contain extra quote characters, escaped somehow e.g. `"a quote \" in an entry"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is doable with :s, as in

`:%s/\("[^"]*"\)\s*,\s*"[^"]*"/\1/g`

Comment: It is not so easy: **column values can contain field separators**

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It's a bit unclear, but I interpret the question as meaning that the column values can contain extra *commas*: the example and I *think* the approaches included in the question support this. This solution should therefore work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Csv.vim is suggested by its author in GitHub. Perl script runs an external command outputting to a new buffer in Vim.

I tested them on a CSV file with about 400 rows and 30 columns: the for-loop solution hangs up (never getting completed) while perl solution has an instant completion.

**Csv.vim**

```
for i in range(100,1,-2) | exe "DeleteColumn" i | endfor
```

**Perl in vim**

```
 :new | r !perl -nle'$i=0;s/^"|"$//g;print map{$i++&1?"":"$_ "}split(/","/)' "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on whether column values can contain extra `"` characters, as well as the extra commas that you include in your example.

If the answer is no, then you can record a simple recursive macro to remove every second column on a single line:

1. `gg`: Move to start of file,
2. `qqq`: Clear the `q` register: this is necessary for recursive macros,
3. `qq`: Start recording in the `q` register,
4. `f"`: Find the end of the first entry,
5. `2dt"`: Delete to end of second entry,
6. `ll`: Move to start of third entry,
7. `@q`: Replay the `q` macro. This is currently empty, so nothing happens,
8. `q`: Finish recording,
9. `u`: Undo change.

You can then play this macro on every line of the file with the command:

```
:%normal @q
```

This may look like a lot of steps, but note that steps 1–3 and steps 7–9 are essentially boilerplate, and don't require any thought, and the remaining steps 4–6 are simple normal-mode movement/editing operations that are just as quick, for me. Macros are always more efficient to *use* than they look when they are written down.

Note also that if the number of columns is always the same (as in your example), you don't even need a recursive macro. You can just replay an even simpler macro the correct number of times:

```
gg qq f" 2dt" ll q u

:%normal 3@q
```

If column values *can* contain extra quotes, you could in all likelihood still use this approach, but the macro would be more complicated, so another solution might work better.